# How to get data of modal forms using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My code is getting the data from PHP, then generating modals according to the number of items I have in the db. I have tried several solution of SO,  how to get button ids according to the button clicked but don't find any solution.

When I click the any button generated, it sends only the first item of the modal form instead of the item clicked. I think the problem is the buttons not having unique id's. How to ensure that they have unique id's. Below is the code:

```
 <div id="feedback">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#feedback-modal-<?php echo $item['payment_id']; ?>">Add Payment</button>
 </div>
 <div id="feedback-modal-<?php echo $item['payment_id']; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <h3>Add Payment</h3>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                 <form class="feedback" name="feedback" method="POST">
                     <strong>Full Name</strong>
                     <br>
                     <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" class="input-xlarge" value="<?php echo $item['full_name'] ?? 'Unknown';?>">
                     <br><br>
                     <strong>Subtotal</strong>
                     <br>
                     <input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" class="input-xlarge" value="<?php echo $item['subtotal'] ?? '0';?>">
                     <br><br>
                     <strong>Payment Method</strong>
                     <br>
                     <select name="paymentMethod" id="paymentMethod">
                         <option value="Cash1">Cash1</option>
                         <option value="Cash2">Cash2</option>
                         <option value="Cash3">Cash3</option>
                     </select>
                     <br><br>
                     <strong>Received by</strong>
                     <br>
                     <input type="text" name="receivedBy" id="receivedBy" class="input-xlarge" value="<?php echo $item['received_by'] ?? 'Unknown';?>">
                 </form>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button class="btn btn-success" id="payment-btn" name="payment-btn">Send</button>
                 <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that the button for sending the data have the same id, and ajax only accepts one id as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#payment-btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin-server.php",
            // url: "../Database/Payment.php",
            data: 'contactFrmSubmit=1&fullName=' + $('#fullName').val() + '&subtotal=' + $('#subtotal').val() + '&paymentMethod=' + $('#paymentMethod').val() + '&receivedBy=' + $('#receivedBy').val(),
            success: function (message) {
                $("#feedback").html(message)
                $("#feedback-modal").modal('hide');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How can I have different id's?

Comment: _"but how do I make sure they do have unique id's"_ - why do you still need to ask that, considering that you _are_ already creating unique IDs for the modal element itself, and in the `data-target` attribute of the button that is responsible for opening that particular modal?

Comment: I want to have different ids for the buttons that are generated automatically from the DB or how I can access the send button of the individual modals so that when I send the data, it can be the correct data and not for the first form each time.

Comment: There are _countless_ other ways to select, or navigate to, an element in the DOM, besides IDs. In situations like this, it often makes the most sense to base your selection on the relationship elements have to each other. jQuery has the `find` method to only select elements "within" another element, or a `context` parameter to achieve the same thing with just `$(...)` Using those, you should be able to make most of this work using classes instead of IDs. (Opening the modals probably still requires IDs, because of how that is implemented in Bootstrap. But that part you had already covered.)